# Implementing Laravel 7 Passport authentification with Nuxt frontend

Tags: laravel, authentication, cors, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I have installed and configured Laravel 7.3 Passport, then I made a fresh install of Nuxt.js and configure it as explained [here](https://github.com/pktharindu/nuxt-laravel-passport-example) (works perfect with Laravel 5.8.34). But when logging in, I get a CORS error message in the javascript console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-laravel.test/oauth/token' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Below is how I configured Nuxt.js:

`pages/index.vue`

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <strong>Home Page</strong>
      <pre>Both guests and logged in users can access!</pre>
      <nuxt-link to="/login">Login</nuxt-link>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

`pages/login.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              v-model="user.username"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              v-model="user.password"
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </div>
          <button
            @click.prevent="passwordGrantLogin"
            type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
          >
            Login with Password Grant
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'guest',
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    async passwordGrantLogin() {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('password_grant', {
        data: {
          grant_type: 'password',
          client_id: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET,
          scope: '',
          username: this.user.username,
          password: this.user.password
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`pages/profile.vue`

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <div>
      <strong>Strategy</strong>
      <pre>{{ strategy }}</pre>
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>User</strong>
      <pre>{{ $auth.user }}</pre>
    </div>
    <button @click="logout" class="btn btn-primary">
      Logout
    </button>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  data() {
    return {
      strategy: this.$auth.$storage.getUniversal('strategy')
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    async logout() {
      await this.$auth.logout()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`nuxt.config.js` (partly)

```
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt'
  ],

  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.LARAVEL_ENDPOINT,
    // proxy: true
  },

  // Proxy module configuration
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: process.env.LARAVEL_ENDPOINT,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/'
      }
    }
  },

  // Auth module configuration
  auth: {
    // redirect: {
    //   login: '/login',
    //   logout: '/',
    //   callback: '/login',
    //   home: '/profile'
    // },
    // strategies: {
    //   'laravel.passport': {
    //     url: '/',
    //     client_id: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID,
    //     client_secret: process.env.PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET
    //   }
    // }
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      password_grant: {
        _scheme: 'local',
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/oauth/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'access_token'
          },
          logout: false,
          user: {
            url: 'api/auth/me',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'user'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

`middleware/guest.js`

```
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  if (store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/')
  }
}
```

`.env`

```
LARAVEL_ENDPOINT='http://my-laravel.test/'
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_ID=6
PASSPORT_PASSWORD_GRANT_SECRET=p9PMlcO***********GFeNY0v7xvemkP
```

As you can see in the commented code source, I also tried unsuccessfully with proxy as suggested [here](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/) and with auth strategy `laravel.passport` as suggested [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-passport.html).

Comment: Same error here, working on it.

Comment: Have you tried to edit `config/cors.php` in Laravel and replaced `'paths' => ['api/*']` by `'paths' => ['*']` ? I'm now actually struggling with using `laravel.passport` strategy in `nuxt.config.js`.

Comment: Hi, I have this problem on auth middleware, perhaps, you have a solution. Thank you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497179/nuxt-js-using-laravel-passport-redirects-to-login-page-after-page-refresh-on-sec

Comment: @Wonderman  Have you fixed `middleware:auth` problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497179/nuxt-js-using-laravel-passport-redirects-to-login-page-after-page-refresh-on-sec

Answer (score 0):

Go to cors.php and make sure you have oauth endpoint like api/* or laravel sanctum.

You have to clear config and cache before test again

Comment: please add more explain and commands that need if you can