# Nuxt js using laravel passport redirects to login page after page refresh on secured pages

Tags: nuxt.js

I am using laravel passport for my NUXT authentication. I am following this doc:

https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-passport.html#usage

I can login successfully on my nuxt-app. It redirects to dashboard after login wherein dashboard has `middleware:'auth'`. The problem is. when I refresh the dashboard, it redirects back to login page. On js console, `$auth.isAuthenticated` returns true, but on SSR, it is false. I guess, the problem is on `middleware:auth`, I'm not sure. I already searched on google but there is no solution. I tried this already:

https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/478

My code looks like this below:

[Implementing Laravel 7 Passport authentification with Nuxt frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979264/implementing-laravel-7-passport-authentification-with-nuxt-frontend)

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `http_only` cookie is not available with SSR. So you will need to make a nuxt plugin. And there you should check if the `access_token` does not exists and `user` exists in the cookies (when the user logs in, you should make a cookie with user info or user id, personally I would use Vuex combined with [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate)). And if the user exists in the cookies, and `access_token` does not exists, then you should refresh the token.

`plugins/refresh-token.js`

```js
import clientCookies from 'js-cookie';

/**
 * For refreshing the token on page reload.
 *
 * @param  {Object} context.store
 * @return {Void}
 */
export default function ({store}) {
  window.onNuxtReady(() => {
    let token = clientCookies.get('x-access-token');
    let user = store.getters['user/currentUser'];

    if (user && ! token) {
      store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken')
        .catch(errors => {
          store.dispatch('auth/signUserOut');
        });
    }
  });
}
```

For more information, read this [post](https://dev.to/stefant123/secure-authentication-in-nuxt-spa-with-laravel-as-back-end-19a9)

Comment: from your post, I cannot retrieve the `request()->cookie('cookie')`. 

https://dev.to/smzapp/comment/14dgi

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue just recently, while this answer may not be useful to the op, I believe it may be useful to others in the future.

This is what we did below, under your api routes which can be found in routes/api.php , add the nuxt js domain accessing the laravel application api,  use the code below - make sure you format specifically for your own use case

```
$landingRoutes = function () {
//your routes
};
Route::group(['domain' => config('app.DASHBOARD_DOMAIN1')], $landingRoutes);
Route::group(['domain' => config('app._DASHBOARD_DOMAIN2')], $landingRoutes);
```

I wrote about it on my blog too [here](https://oluomotoso.com/nuxt-js-using-laravel-passport-redirects-to-login-page-after-page-refresh-on-secured-pages-fix)